# select derived class file global variable by base class virtual function

Tags: c++, global-variables, derived-class

This is a common problem I am facing.
I am intended to write a derived class for an existing code. Let me provide the code snippet (just example):

**Base_class_file:**

```
const int addr=0xA;

Base_class::Read()
{
  return *addr;
}
```

Please note, the addr variable is a global variable in base class file.
Now, I am writing the derived class because to change some functionality and also to change the addr. I would like to re-use the Read() method, and just mention the new addr(let's say 0xB) in the derived class file.
Since this variable is a global variable, how do I mention to the base class Read() method to use the addr=0xB than the 0xA ??

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about....

```
virtual int & GetTheGlobalVariable() const {return addr;}
```

and then overriding that method in the subclass to return a different result?

Comment: I have like 40-50 global variables which includes addresses, bitsets masks etc etc. In this case, shouldnt I be having the GetTheGlobalVariable() for all these variables ?

Comment: Global variables in general are not a good idea.  Perhaps you can redesign your program to avoid them?

Comment: Yes, thats what I finally did! I had to get consent from the superiors to touch the existing code. But, I brought all these variables under the class. Thus, I can assign values based on the object created.

Answer (score 0):

You override it in the derived class and have it return `0xB`. Of course this works only if the base class `Read` method is declared `virtual`.

Comment: This is always a possibility. But, the real scenario is not as simple as mentioned in the example code. There are 'n' number of functions like Read() and each function is of 100+ lines.

Comment: So, if I override all those functions just to get the global variable mentioned in the derived class file, I think it will work, but I will be creating a lot of duplicate code.